# Disabling Old Area Paths

Tags: azure-devops

how can i disable old area path in Azure DevOps so that new or legacy work items can not be assigned to them as well as remove the area paths that were disabled from the area path drop down in a work item? I still want to be able to query off of these legacy old area paths so I do not want to delete them.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to use the security of the Area path to Deny permission to edit work items in that area.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> remove the area paths that were disabled from the area path drop down
>   in a work item?

For this demand , I am afraid this is not feasible in azure devops. There is currently no method to make a specific area disappear from the drop-down list of creating work items.
If you want to remove the area from the drop down list, you can only choose to delete it.

So the workaround given by Matt is a good choice.Although this does not make the particular area disappear from the drop-down list, but when you click Save, there will be an warning message(TF237111: The current user does not have permissions to save work items under the specified area path.) to prevent you from completing the creation of this work item.This also satisfies your need to disable the area.